# Lie derivative and commutator.

Tags: smooth-manifolds

On Do Carmo's book Riemannian Geometry in the chapter $0$ we have the following theorem:

> Let $X,Y$ be differentiable vector fields on a differentiable manifold $M$, let $p\in M$ and let $\phi_t$ be the local flow of $X$ in a neighborhood $U$ of $p$. Then
>   $$[X,Y](p)=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\displaystyle\frac{1}{t}[Y-d\phi_tY](\phi_t(p))$$

To prove this theorem he use the following lemma:

> $h:(-\delta,\delta)\times U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable mapping with $h(0,q)=0$ for all $q\in U$. Then there exist a differentiable mapping $g:(-\delta,\delta)\times U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $h(t,q)=t g(t,q)$; in particular,
>   $$g(0,q)=\displaystyle\frac{\partial h(t,q)}{\partial t}\large|_{t=0}$$

I have some doubts in the prove. For completeness I post it here:

> **Proof:** Let $f$ be a differentiable function in a neigboorhood of $p$. Putting
>   $$h(t,q)=f(\phi_t(q))-f(q)$$
>   and applying the lemma we obtain a differentiable function $g(t,q)$ such that 
>   $$f\circ\phi_t(q)=f(q)+tg(t,q)\text{ and } g(0,q)=Xf(q)$$
>   Accordingly
>   $$((d\phi_t Y)f)(\phi_t(p))=Y(f\circ\phi_t))(p)=Yf(p)+t(Yg(t,p))$$
>   Therefore
>   $$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}[Y-d\phi_tY]f(\phi_tp)=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\displaystyle\frac{(Yf)(\phi_tp)-Yf(p)}{t}-(Yg(0,p)) $$
>   $$=(X(Yf))(p)-(Y(Xf))(p)$$
>   $$=((XY-YX)f(p)=([X,Y]f)(p)$$

I do not understand two details in this prove:

Why $g(0,q)=Xf(q)$ I know that it follow from the lemma and the definition of local flow, but I want some detail to prove this claim.

Why
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\displaystyle\frac{(Yf)(\phi_tp)-Yf(p)}{t}=(X(Yf))(p)$$
Why this equation holds?

Thanks!

Comment: Better than do Carmo: Try Loomis/Sternberg Advanced Calculus, Chapt. 9.6 or
Abraham/Marsden Foundations of Mechanics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace in

$$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\displaystyle\frac{(f)(\phi_tp)-f(p)}{t}=(X(f))(p)$$

function $f$ by $Yf$.

$Yf$ is an $\mathbb{R}-$valued function. Flow of $X$, $\phi_t$ remains unchanged.

$$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\displaystyle\frac{(Yf)(\phi_tp)-Yf(p)}{t}=(X(Yf))(p)$$